# For a real number x, define the fractional part of x as fp (x) := x − floor(x)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For a real number x, define the fractional part of x as fp (x) := x − floor(x).

Prove that 0 ≤ fp (x) < 1.

Here is my proof

By the way of contradiction assume 0 > fp(x) >= 1.  Suppose x is an element of R. Then x - floor(x) = m s.t. m is an element of rational numbers.  (i.e. 1.2-floor(1.2) = .2)  so m > 0, and m < 1.  This contradicts our assumption, Thus the statement is true.

Can someone help me on this.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the answer to your previous question.

Comment: How can you assume something like $0>fp(x)\geq1$??? No such real number exists.

Comment: There is a mistake in your assumption.  Remember that $0\leq fp(x)<1$ means $0\leq fp(x)$ *and* $fp(x)<1$.  To do a contradiction proof, this statement must be negated and the *and* becomes an *or*.  Therefore, $0>fp(x)$ *or* $fp(x)\geq 1$.

Comment: $0\le x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ comes from the definition of $\lfloor x\rfloor$: the largest integer _less than or equal to_ $x$.

Comment: hey @MattSamuel how can I use my previous answer for this question.  Can you please elaborate a little.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use it to show that $\lfloor x\rfloor\in (x-1,x]$ because that interval must contain an integer.

Comment: got it thank you @MattSamuel